# Type of the first parameter of a member function in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I have written a metafunction to retrieve the type of the first parameter of a member function, which of course receives one or more parameters. The code I have written is as follow:

```
template <typename...> struct parameter;

template < typename O, typename A, typename R, typename... Args>
struct parameter <R (O::*)(A, Args...)  > {
     using first_param = A;
};
```

I use this meta function as follow:

```
using mem_fn = void(mem_type::*)(std::vector<int>);
using f_pm = parameter<mem_fn>::first_param;
```

and it compiles and works. But when I have a class:

```
struct mem_type{

    void update(std::vector<int>) {

    }
};
```

and use my metafunction as follow:

```
using mem_fn = decltype(mem_type::update);
using f_pm = parameter<mem_fn>::first_param;
```

the code does not compiles and visual studio 2013 gives: error C2027: use of undefined type `parameter<mem_fn>`.

Does anyone knows the reason for this error?

Comment: Does `using mem_fn = decltype(&mem_type::update);` work? I've seen similar issues in the past and being more explicit on the address has helped. Here to match your member function pointer specialisation.

Comment: MSVC `using` support is flaky.  Try `typedef`?  Oh, and `&mem_type::update` might also help.  Bah, @Niall beat me to the 2nd one.  `mem_type::update` isn't a valid way to get a pointer to it: unlike functions, member functions to not auto-decay the same way.

Comment: Your specialization matches a pointer-to-member-function, so `decltype(&mem_type::update)`.

Comment: @Snps [No it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25e840127ca0ab2e).

Comment: It works fine here using g++ (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2 (if you supply the ampersand decltype(&mem_type::update). I suspect VS2013 could be flaky with the use of using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, an *id-expression* naming a nonstatic member function (`mem_type::update` in this case) can't be used as an unevaluated operand (such as the operand of `decltype`).  §5.1.1 [expr.prim.general]/p13 (footnote omitted):

> An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static
>   member function of a class can only be used:
>
> - as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member’s class or a class derived from that
>     class, or
> - to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
> - if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

§7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple]/p4:

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand
>   (Clause 5).

And even if `update` were a regular function, `decltype` would produce a function type rather than a function pointer type, and your specialization matches a pointer-to-member-function type.

You need to created a pointer-to-member-function with `&` - i.e., `decltype(&mem_type::update)`.

Comment: Exactly (nice answer)

Comment: Good answer. Is there a better way to accomplish the task of getting the first parameter of a member function?

Comment: @RaulAlonso You actually need 11 extra specializations (in addition to the one you have) to handle the various combinations of cv- and ref-qualifiers, but I'm not aware of any other way to do it. Also, the base template `parameter` shouldn't be variadic.